# Closing A Captivate SCORM Session

Tags: javascript, adobe, scorm

When you click the exit button in a Captivate Lesson that is Published to SCORM the application will not exit. I tried all of the posted methods. They did not work. Captivate doesn't handle javascript in version 7 the same. After many attempts I finally found a hook I could use. The problem was primarily caused by Adobe never Firing LMSFinish. (odd since there are two requirements to be SCORM compliant with training, 1. Fire LMSInitialize and 2. Fire LMSFinish.) Once you tell the LMS you are done, the LMS can cleanup the window. A web training module CANNOT close a window using window.close. So onto the solution.

Find Utilities.js  it is in the $CaptivateInstallFolder/Templates/Publish/LMS/Standard/SCORM/default/js  folder.

Find the following...

```
function DoCPExit()
{
    if(window != window.parent && window.parent && window.parent.hasOwnProperty("DoCPExit"))
    {
        window.parent.DoCPExit();
    }
    else
    {
        window.close();
    }
}
```

and add the following ...

```
function DoCPExit()
{

    if(SCORM2004_objAPI){SCORM2004_CallTerminate();}
    if(SCORM_objAPI){SCORM_CallLMSFinish();}

    /* The code below will only work if there is a parent. No parent. No close.*/
    if(window != window.parent && window.parent && window.parent.hasOwnProperty("DoCPExit"))
    {
        window.parent.DoCPExit();
    }
    else
    {
        window.close();
    }
}
```

I answered my own question, but I thought someone might benefit from my pain. The LMS can close the window, because the LMS opened it.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying it won't close properly even if you click the "X" control (e.g., part of the SCORM controls inside the Window)? Or is this only when you close the browser window itself?

Comment: The x won't close the window. A window can't close itself. Only a parent window can close it.